# Using @azure/event-hubs sending message always run into a timeout

Tags: javascript, azure, browser, azure-active-directory, azure-eventhub

I am trying to send a message to the configured eventhub for implicit grand flow.
I try to get the following [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/main/sdk/eventhub/event-hubs/samples/v5/browser) to run for sending to event hub. I get to the point when the user/client needs allow the azure application. But after then when I am using the created producer - I get a timeout after 2 minutes. (The request with message_id "xxx" to "$cbs" endpoint timed out. Please try again later.)

What can causes this type of error? When I am producing messages in .net everything is working fine. And if its because of auth issue (because of the complex configuration) I would get an other error (like I got before I set it up correctly)

Some other infos:
I gave the app registration only "Azure Event Hubs Data Send" role and I put the role to the app twice one time on the subscription level and one directly in the event hub (IAM). Can this double role cause an error - no or?

Comment: When I am creating the producer with a connection string than the message will be send without the timeout error. So it has something to do with the  implicit grand flow process...
not working: const producer = new EventHubProducerClient(fullyQualifiedNamespace, eventHubName, credential);
working: const producer = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName);

Comment: Does the user signing in also have the Azure Event Hubs Data Send role assigned to them?

Comment: Yes ok when I am giving the user the specific - then is working...